# Reload parent page on fancybox transitionOut

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox to show Iframe within it like this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {                          

                $("#button").click(function() {
                $("#iframe").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'fadeIn',
                'transitionOut'     : 'reload()'
                }).click();
            });
});
```

Iframe within this fancybox has some action & my parent page shows its status.

So What I want is,  as soon as I close `['transitionOut']` fancybox, my parent page gets reload..

How can I achieve this ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found answer :**

```
                 $("#button").click(function() {
                 $("#iframe").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'fadeIn',
                'onClosed'          : function() {
                                      parent.location.reload(true); ;
                                      }
                }).click();
            });
```